# JDBCTemplate.queryForList returns empty list

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate, spring-jdbc

Could you please help to figure out why following Java code returns empty list

```
return this.getJdbcTemplate().queryForList(
    "select cn from group g, group_relationship r, " +
    "group_member m where g.name='administratorGroup' and g.group_id=r.group_id " +
    "and r.member_id=m.member_id and m.cn like ?", 
    String.class, 
    new Object[] { cn + "%" });
```

I tested using sqlplus, replace ? with 'd%', The query returns a list of cn start with d.

Answer (score 0):

```
new Object[] { cn + "%" )
```

is not correct at the end unless the variable `cn` is `d`.

Comment: Thank you for both of you, first, cn is not null and second cn=d because I was doing JUnit testing

Answer (score 0):

Make sure You're not calling this for cn == null, as in such case cn + "%" becomes "null%" and that's why it probably returns 0 records.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for everybody's help, The problem is solved, I was unaware JUnit test is using in-memory db, trying to compare the JUnit test result with test db, after add entries in in-memory db, test return correct result